# list comprehension on elements of varying length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Some of the elements in my list are a bit longer and need different treatment. This list looks like this:

```
a = [['red', 'square', 'up'], ['red', 'circle'], 
     ['blue', 'triangle'], ['blue', 'square'], 
     ['blue', 'octagon'], ['blue', 'diamond', 'down']]
```

I can almost get it do do what I want like this:

```
[[x[0], x[1] + 's'] for x in a]
```

which gives

```
[['red', 'squares'],
 ['red', 'circles'],
 ['blue', 'triangles'],
 ['blue', 'squares'],
 ['blue', 'octagons'],
 ['blue', 'diamonds']]
```

but that is losing information from the longer elements. The desired output is:

```
[['red', 'squares', 'up1'], ['red', 'circles'], 
['blue', 'triangles'], ['blue', 'squares'], 
 ['blue', 'octagons'], ['blue', 'diamonds', 'down1']]
```

Just doing this

```
[[x[0], x[1] + 's', x[2] + '1'] for x in a]
```

...unsurprisingly results in an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want the middle element to have an "s" appended to it and if there is a third element, a "1" should be appended to it.

Comment: does the ordering of the elements in the output list matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error because sometimes your `x` has `2` elements and sometimes `3`. I modified your code to handle this:

```
a = [['red', 'square', 'up'], ['red', 'circle'], 
     ['blue', 'triangle'], ['blue', 'square'], 
     ['blue', 'octagon'], ['blue', 'diamond', 'down']]
t = [[x[0], x[1] + 's'] if len(x) == 2 else [x[0], x[1] + 's', x[2] + '1'] for x in a]
print(t)
```

Output:

> [['red', 'squares', 'up1'], ['red', 'circles'], ['blue', 'triangles'], ['blue', 'squares'], ['blue', 'octagons'], ['blue', 'diamonds', 'down1']]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `zip()`:

```
a = [['red', 'square', 'up'],
     ['red', 'circle'],
     ['blue', 'triangle'],
     ['blue', 'square'],
     ['blue', 'octagon'],
     ['blue', 'diamond', 'down']]

endings = ['', 's', '1']

[[i + j for i, j in zip(i, endings)] for i in a]
```

Result:

```
[['red', 'squares', 'up1'],
 ['red', 'circles'],
 ['blue', 'triangles'],
 ['blue', 'squares'],
 ['blue', 'octagons'],
 ['blue', 'diamonds', 'down1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `len()` of each `elem` in the `list`, and manipulate accordingly:

**For understanding**:

```
a = [['red', 'square', 'up'], ['red', 'circle'],
     ['blue', 'triangle'], ['blue', 'square'],
     ['blue', 'octagon'], ['blue', 'diamond', 'down']]

for elem in a:
    if len(elem) < 3:
        print([elem[0], elem[1] + "s"])
    else:
        print([elem[0], elem[1] + "s " + elem[2]+ "1"])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['red', 'squares up1']
['red', 'circles']
['blue', 'triangles']
['blue', 'squares']
['blue', 'octagons']
['blue', 'diamonds down1']
```

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
print([[x[0], x[1] + 's'] if len(x) < 3 else [x[0], x[1] + 's', x[2] + '1'] for x in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in case you only want to check whether the nested list has a len > 2:

```
[[x[0], x[1] + 's'] if len(x) == 2 else [x[0], x[1]+'s', x[2]+'1'] for x in a]
```

Output:

```
[['red', 'squares', 'up1'],
 ['red', 'circles'],
 ['blue', 'triangles'],
 ['blue', 'squares'],
 ['blue', 'octagons'],
 ['blue', 'diamonds', 'down1']]
```